# Babel overrides is not allowed in preset options react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I trying to add a router [react native navigation  v2](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/) to this starter project on [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html), but I have a problem that is connected with babel package (probably). When I run

```
react-native run-android
```

I have this error in Metro Bundler:

> loading dependency graph, done.
>   : bundling failed: Error: [BABEL] D:\react—native\projecti\index.js: .overr ides is not allowed in preset options
>
> at Object.keys.forEach.key (D:\react—native\projecti\node_modules\metro\node odules\Obabel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:71:13)
>   at Array.forEach ()
>   at validate (D:\react—native\projecti\node_modules\metro\node_modules\nabel core\lib\config\validation\options.js:69:21)
>   at instantiatePreset (D:\react—native\projecti\node_modules\metro\node_modul s\l@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:242:36)
>   at cachedFunction (D:\react—native\projecti\node_modules\metro\node_modules\ babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:42:19)
>   at loadPresetDescriptor (D:\react—native\projecti\node_modules\metro\node_mo Iules\ftabel\core\lib\config\full.js:233:45)
>   at config.presets.map.descriptor (D:\react—native\projecti\node_modules\metr I\node_modules\ftabel\core\lib\config\full.js:68:19)
>   at Array.map ()
>   at recurseDescriptors (D:\react—native\projecti\node_modules\metro\node_modu les\Obabel\core\lib\config\full.js:66:38)

Building in console ended successfully.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.56",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.0.2569"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am getting the same error.

Comment: no, i have't. I wanna try do same things on Linux

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you have RN 0.56 which used some beta versions of babel.

I see you have 2 solutions:

**1) Keep RN 0.56 and set correct babel deps**

For RN 0.56 you need to ensure all the @babel/* deps are fixed at version 7.0.0-beta.47 (Please see the change log of 0.56 for those)

**2) Upgrade your project to RN 0.57**

To be able to use latest babel 7 dependencies you will have to migrate your project to RN 0.57.

```
This is what I have for a 0.57.1 project:

"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1",
    .......
  }

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    .....

}
```

**Important**: update `.babelrc` configuration to:

```
{
    "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

More info about RN 0.56, 0.57 change log here:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

More info about babel 7 deps here:

https://new.babeljs.io/docs/en/next/v7-migration.html#versioning-dependencies-blog-2017-12-27-nearing-the-70-releasehtml-peer-dependencies-integrations
https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade

More info about upgrading a RN project to babel 7 here:

[React native upgrade from babel 6 to babel 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681984/react-native-upgrade-from-babel-6-to-babel-7/52717426#52717426)

Note: make sure you remove all node_modules and re-install them and clean local cache after babel versions modifications.

`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all`

Comment: Worked great, thanks for the tip to upgrade to 0.57.