# Babel Unknown option: .caller

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, babel-jest

When I run npm start babel is throwing the following error: **ReferenceError: Unknown option: .caller. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.**

My package.json:

```
{
"private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "^16.5",
    "react-native": "^0.57",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.30.1",
    "react-native-off-canvas-menu": "^0.1.32",
    "react-native-pull-refresh": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^0.5.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.5.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "ree-validate": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.42",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.48.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

I mention that my project is a react native application.
I have no peer dependencies errors. I failed to find any conflicts between the different babel dependencies. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to RN 0.57 change log you need to:

> Ensure that you have all the babel dependencies to version ^7.0.0 (you
>   may also need to add babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0" as a yarn
>   resolution to ensure retro-compatibility)

It seems that you have a `@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.42` not `^7.0.0`.

Here is a configuration that worked for me in RN 0.57.1 and 0.57.2:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52717426/1979861

Also check the `.babelrc` file to be according to RN change.log.

At any point if you get some babel error you can try to clean all cache with something like this (using yarn or npm, depending on what you have):

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && npm start -- --reset-cache
```